# Grouping by and performing count on columns WITHOUT pandas in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, including *family_ID* and *user_ID* for a streaming platform. What I'm trying to do is find which family IDs have the most unique users associated to them within this dataframe
.
The SQL code for this would be:

```
SELECT   TOP 5 family_id,
         Count(distinct user_id) AS user_count
FROM     log_edit
WHERE    family_id <> ''
GROUP BY family_id
ORDER BY user_count DESC;
```

Using pandas I can get the same result using:

```py
df.groupby('family_id')['user_id'].nunique().nlargest(5)
```

My question is, how can I get the same result without using Pandas or SQL at all? I can import the .csv using Pandas but have to do the analysis without it. What's the best way to approach this case?

If it's an array I assume the result would be something like `[1,2,3,4,5] [9,7,7,7,5]`, where 1->5 are family ids and the other array is the number of user id's registered to them (sorted in descending order and limited to 5 results)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking. You have a csv(?) but do not want to use SQL or pandas, but you have not specified how you _do_ want to solve this problem.

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes, I have a csv file and I cannot use pandas except for reading the csv, but perhaps numpy to analyze it. I'm not entirely sure how to approach solving such a problem myself which is why I ask this here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you put `numpy` among the tags, I am assuming you might want to use that. In that case, you can use `np.unique`:

```
import numpy as np

family_id = [9,7,7,7,5,5]
top_k = 2

unique_family_ids, counts = np.unique(family_id, return_counts=True)

# Use - to sort from largest to smallest
sort_idx = np.argsort(-counts)

for idx in sort_idx[:top_k]:
    print(unique_family_ids[idx], 'has', counts[idx], 'unique user_id')
```

If you want to handle missing ids like in the SQL query you'll have to know how these are encoded exactly...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just so I understand correctly, how does that work since the user_id in the other column was not imported?

Also, how can I transform the dataframe with 11 columns, including user_id and family_id to fit this code?

Comment: Sorry maybe I was a bit sloppy in there, I just assumed that every user had a unique user_id; if so, you don't need to use it at all (you don't need to know the specific user id's to know how many they are). If there are repeated rows with the same user id (assuming they are well defined, i.e. the same user_id always maps to the same family_id) you first need to discard duplicates, e.g. by doing `_, unique_id = np.unique(user_id, return_index=True)` and then `family_id = family_id[unique_id]` before doing anything else in the code above

Comment: As for the other columns, you just don't need to use them at all...

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying your first code in this comment: NameError: name 'user_id' is not defined. How can I connect it to the array to define it?